# In Rational Rhapsody 8.0.5 how do set the model to be SysML, not UML?

Tags: rhapsody

I'm taking a class in Systems Engineering Architecture and we are using Rational Rhapsody 8.0.5. According to the manual I am supposed to be able to simply select the Design Manager Client under the Tools menu - but for some reason I don't have that. I am running the program off of a university server through Virtual connection so I don't think I can do anything to the configuration of the software.

Somehow it can be done, because somehow the prof walked me through doing it without me really realizing how, and I didn't capture it in my notes.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting File -> Add Profile To Model and then navigating to your profile folders (I believe in your version they will be in the Rhapsody installation folder). You should be in a directory that looks something like this C:/...../share/profiles/SysML/SysMLProfile_rpy then select the SysML.sbs file.

You may need to reload after that but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

the partial solution by Troa is in the right direction:
- be sure to load first the SysML profile in your model.

- after it you can select in Project Browser the "Project" node and in context menu select: Change To > SysML